# Help with explanation of change of variables (wave equation)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis

I have the wave equation, $u:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, c\in\mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}$,
\begin{gather}
\frac{\partial^2 u(x,t)}{\partial x^2}=\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2 u(x,t)}{\partial t^2} 
\end{gather}
I know the general solution is $u(x,t)=f(x+ct)+g(x-ct)$.

We can show this with the change of variables, $\xi =x+ct$ and $\eta =x-ct$, so $u(\xi, \eta)=f(\xi)+g(\eta)$. And from here it is the chain rule. So far so good.

However, I don't grasp the change of variables. Why can we write $
u(\xi, \eta)=f(\xi)+g(\eta)$? I mean, If I have
$$u(x,t)=f(x+ct)+g(x-ct) \tag 1$$
and introduce $\xi =x+ct$ and $\eta =x-ct$, I solve for $x$, i.e.
\begin{align}
\xi &=x+ct \quad \iff \quad t=\frac{\xi - x}{c} \\
\eta &=x-ct \quad \iff \quad
t=\frac{x-\eta }{c} 
\end{align}
\begin{equation}
\boxed{x=\frac{\xi +\eta}{2}} \tag 2
\end{equation}
And same for $t$, so
\begin{equation}
\boxed{t=\frac{\xi -\eta }{2c}} \tag 3
\end{equation}

> I now change variables in $(1)$, i.e.
> \begin{align}
> u\bigg(\frac{\xi+\eta}{2}, \frac{\xi-\eta}{2c}\bigg)=f(\xi)+g(\eta). \tag 4
> \end{align}
> Why is this wrong? Why is $u(x,t)=u(\xi,\eta) \tag 5$ and not $u(x,t)=u\bigg(\frac{\xi+\eta}{2}, \frac{\xi-\eta}{2c}\bigg)?\; \tag 6$

Comment: Think to $f(x,y)=(x^2-y^2)=(x+y)(x-y)=g(x+y,x-y)=g(u,v)=uv$. Maybe the confusion here arises form the fact that the same symbol is used for $u$.

Answer (score 1):

Because now we are considering the $u$ as a funcion of the two new variables then

$$u(x,t)=u\bigg(\frac{\xi+\eta}{2}, \frac{\xi-\eta}{2c}\bigg)=f(\xi)+g(\eta)=u(\xi,\eta)$$

The confusion arises because the same symbol is used for $u$ but it is justified since, even if the expressions for the two function are different, they represent the same function.